# How can I replace an object key:pair in an Object with a function that returns true or false depending on other properties in the same Object

Tags: javascript

Given the below object, is there a way I can replace the top-level `active:false` line with a method that searches `filterValues` and returns true if it finds any `filterValues` with `active:true`?

```
let object = {
        name: 'Brand',
        field: 'brand',
        type: 'string',
        active: false,
        open: true,
        table: 'Catalogue',
        filterValues: [
          {
            display: 'Schweigen Classic',
            value: 'Schweigen Classic',
            active: false,
            filterGroup: 'brand',
          },
          {
            display: 'Schweigen IN.',
            value: 'Schweigen IN.',
            active: false,
            filterGroup: 'brand',
          },
          {
            display: 'Schweigen X',
            value: 'Schweigen X',
            active: false,
            filterGroup: 'brand',
          },
        ],
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make it a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```
    ...
    get active() {
        return this.filterValues.some(f => f.active)
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks georg, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find method on an array to know if there is a filterValue with active true property and then set the object property to true value.

Your code should be something like this:

```
const hasActiveFilterValue = object.filterValues.find(filterValue => filterValue.active);
if (hasActiveFilterValue) {
  object.active = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some for that and give the active property the boolean value according to the result.

The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function, in your case, 1 not active property inside the filterValues array.

```js
let object = {
        name: 'Brand',
        field: 'brand',
        type: 'string',
        open: true,
        table: 'Catalogue',
        filterValues: [
          {
            display: 'Schweigen Classic',
            value: 'Schweigen Classic',
            active: false,
            filterGroup: 'brand',
          },
          {
            display: 'Schweigen IN.',
            value: 'Schweigen IN.',
            active: false,
            filterGroup: 'brand',
          },
          {
            display: 'Schweigen X',
            value: 'Schweigen X',
            active: false,
            filterGroup: 'brand',
          },
        ],
      };
      
object.active = !object.filterValues.some(x => !x.active);
console.log(object);
```